# Convert Map<Integer, List<Strings> to Map<String, List<Integer>

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap

I'm having a hard time converting a `Map` containing some integers as *keys* and a list of random strings as *values*.

*E.g. :*

```
1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
2 = ["a", "b", "z"]
3 = ["z"]
```

I want to transform it into a `Map` of distinct strings as *keys* and lists the integers as *values*.

*E.g. :*

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2]
c = [1]
z = [2,3]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> integerListMap; // initial list is already populated

List<String> distinctStrings = new ArrayList<>();
SortedMap<String, List<Integer>> stringListSortedMap = new TreeMap<>();

for(Integer i: integers) {
    integerListMap.put(i, strings);
    distinctStrings.addAll(strings);
}

distinctStrings = distinctStrings.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

for(String s : distinctStrings) {
    distinctStrings.put(s, ???);
}
```

Comment: Iterate over your source `Map` and populate the result directly in that loop. There's no need to create a `distinctStrings` List.

Comment: Your initial data and result is written in such a way that one can't tell if you want the result in sorted key order, encounter order, or you don't care.   Map keys are unordered by design.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over your source map's value and put each value into the target map.

```
final Map<String, List<Integer>> target = new HashMap<>();
for (final Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry = source.entrySet()) {
  for (final String s : entry.getValue()) {
    target.computeIfAbsent(s, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey());
  }
}
```

Or with the Stream API by abusing `Map.Entry` to build the inverse:

```
final Map<String, List<Integer>> target = source.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> Map.entry(s, e.getKey()))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e::getKey, Collectors.mapping(e::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Although this might not be as clear as introducing a new custom type to hold the inverted mapping.

Another alternative would be using a bidirectial map. Many libraries come implementations of these, such as Guava.

Comment: Arghs! That's what you get for not using var. Stupid, careless typos. Thanks for editing!

Comment: that's what happens when you don't have an IDE available I guess :) you're welcome.

Comment: Looks like the OP may want the keys in sorted (or at least encounter order).  You may want to change to a `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap.`

Comment: @WJS where does it state that? But yes, `LinkedHashMap` will keep keys in insertion order, `TreeMap` in natural order or as defined by the specified `Comparator` instance

Comment: @knittl  It doesn't state that.  I posed that question to the OP.  But based on the initial data and resultant map, it is not possible to tell since they are such simple examples.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to apply `distinct()` since you're storing the data into the `Map` and *keys* are guaranteed to be unique.

You can flatten the entries of the source map, so that only one string (let's call it `name`) and a single integer (let's call it `number`) would correspond to a stream element, and then group the data by string.

To implement this problem using streams, we can utilize [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation to perform one-to-many transformation. And it's a good practice to define a custom type for that purpose as a Java 16 [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html), or a class (you can also use a `Map.Entry`, but note that approach of using a custom type is more advantages because it allows writing [self-documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code)).

In order to collect the data into a `TreeMap` you can make use of the three-args version of [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) which allows to specify *mapFactory*.

```
record NameNumber(String name, Integer number) {}
        
Map<Integer, List<String>> dataByProvider = Map.of(
    1, List.of("a", "b", "c"),
    2, List.of("a", "b", "z"),
    3, List.of("z")
);
        
NavigableMap<String, List<Integer>> numbersByName = dataByProvider.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
        .map(name -> new NameNumber(name, entry.getKey()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        NameNumber::name,
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(NameNumber::number, Collectors.toList())
    ));
    
numbersByName.forEach((name, numbers) -> System.out.println(name + " -> " + numbers));
```

*Output:*

```
a -> [2, 1]
b -> [2, 1]
c -> [1]
z -> [3, 2]
```

***Sidenote:*** while using `TreeMap` it's more beneficial to use `NavigableMap` as an abstract type because it allows to access methods like `higherKey()`, `lowerKey()`, `firstEntry()`, `lastEntry()`, etc. which are declared in the `SortedMap` interface.